# Is there a way to assign the same value to 2 css properties at once?

Tags: css, sass, less

Using `CSS, LESS, or Sass` can you assign the same value to 2 css properties at once?

Just like:

`.c1, c2 {sameValue}`

But instead like this:

```
.c2 { background-color:, color: sameValue}
```

Comment: Well, you can assign `sameValue` to a variable, and use that variable for both of your properties - but I don't think it can be done as you've written.

Comment: LESS: `@c1: red` `@c2: @c1`, the same in SASS: `$c1: red` `$c2: $c1`. In Stylus you can get the value of another property: http://stylus-lang.com/docs/variables.html#property-lookup. In CSS you have `currentColor` and Custom properties to get something similar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this with CSS.

The easiest way to do this is use a variable. Here's how you'd do that in LESS

```
@color: red;
.demo {
  background-color: @color;
  color: @color;
}
```

and the same thing in Sass

```
$color: red;
.demo {
  background-color: $color;
  color: $color;
}
```

But you can also achieve the power you want. Here's one way you could do it in LESS:

```
.properties(@properties, @value, @i: 0) when (@i < length(@properties)) {
  @property: extract(@properties, @i + 1);   // get the property
  @{property}: @value;                       // write the style
  .properties(@properties, @value, (@i + 1)) // loop
}

.demo {
  @props: background-color, color;
  .properties(@props, red)
}
```

will compile to your desired

```
.demo {
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
}
```

**How's it work?**

- `.demo` calls the `.properties` [parametric LESS mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature), passing a *list* (sometimes called an array in other SO questions about CSS/etc) of properties (`.properties`'s `@properties` parameter; in this example, `@props`) and the value to assign to all of them (`.properties`'s `@value` parameter; in this example, `red`).
- note that `.properties` has a counter parameter `@i` with a default value of `0`.
- `.properties` has a LESS [CSS guard](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature) that checks to see if `@i` is less than the number of properties it was passed (held in `@properties`). It is! (`@i` is `0`, and the properties' list is certain to be at least `1`) Okay, so we're allowed past the guard.
- Get the name of the property: use [LESS's `extract()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-extract) on the first item in the list (we need to say `@i + 1` because we started the `@i` counter at `0`. we could have also started `@i` at `1`, and guarded with `when (@i < (length(@properties) + 1))` but that's harder to read)
- *At last: write the style.* [interpolate the variable](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation) holding the property name (`@property`) as a string (`@{property}`), and give it the value we originally passed to `.properties` in `.demo` (`@value`)
- [LESS loop!](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) Run `.properties` again, but advance the counter `@i` one: `.properties(staysTheSame, staysTheSame, (@i + 1))`
- `.properties` will run until it's looped through all the items in its `@properties` list. After that, `@i` will equal `length(@properties)`, so we won't pass the `when (@i < length(@properties))` guard.

---

Note that @props could be defined within `.test`, as above, or anywhere where `.test` will have access to it, and same for the value. You might end up with

```
@props: background-color, color;
@val: red;
@val2: green;
.properties {...}
.demo {
  border-color: @val2;
  .properties(@props, @val)
}
.demo2 {
  .properties(@props, @val2)
}
```

Comment: edit: on second thought, I prefer `...@i:1) when (@i <= length(@properties)) {@property: extract(@properties, @i);...`

Answer (score 3):

If your [browser supports](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) [Custom Properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/) (AKA CSS Variables) you can define a custom property for reuse:

```
.foo {
  --example: red;
  background-color: var(--example);
  color: var(--example);
}
```

Otherwise you'll need to rely on a preprocessor such as LESS:

```
.foo {
  @example: red;
  background-color: @example;
  color: @example;
}
```

or Sass:

```
.foo {
  $example: red;
  background-color: $example;
  color: $example;
}
```

As far as being able to chain properties, I'm not aware of any preprocessor or specification that allows for that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can in the way you described, you would need to use a variable. However you can achieve something similar with properties that share the same namespace.

```
.funky {
  font: {
   family: fantasy;
   size: 30em;
   weight: bold;
  }
}
```

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested_properties

Answer (score 0):

In [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) is possible to do the *Property lookup*, which allows you to use properties in the current or closest parent ancestor and use it for calculations.

For you specific case you could write:

```
.demo
  color: red
  background-color: @color
```

which produces this CSS:

```
.demo {
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}
```

It is a [feature asked also for LESS](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2433) but currently there are not plans to develop it. Currently in LESS (and in SASS) you must use one of already suggested solutions, passing by an additional variable.

Comment: "but currently there are not plans to develop it" - actually [it's implemented](https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/2654) more than year ago. It's just not enough human-resources to polish all the new features for v3 release soon.

Comment: Ops sorry, I did not know it. I hope that new v3 version would arrive in short times

Answer (score 0):

With Stylus you can do this way using [iteration](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/iteration.html) and [interpollation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html) :

```css
.modal
  position : absolute
  for bord in top bottom left right
    {bord}: 1em
  for larg in  width min-width height min-height
    {larg}: auto
  for maxl in  max-width max-height
    {maxl}: none
```